# Outer and inner divs with zoom transition

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, an outer one that sets a background image and an inner div that displays some "Click here" text. I want to implement a zoom on hover effect that works whenever the mouse hovers over any element in the outer box, but for the moment it's only working when the mouse is between the bounds of the inner and the outer divs. The effect should happen also when the mouse is inside the inner div. Here's the demo of my code : https://codepen.io/joaoricardotg/pen/jOPvomp

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="OuterBox"></div>
        <div class="InnerBox">
            <div>
                <h2>CLICK HERE</h2>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.limiter { 
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.OuterBox {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(https://www.dictionary.com/e/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vscogirl1000x700.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    position: absolute;
}

.OuterBox:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}


/* Overlay */
.OuterBox::after {
    content: "";
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.InnerBox {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: white solid 5px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/q9zogke4/)
You just need to wrap your inner div with outer div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `position: absolute;`, so you can just reverse the order of you `.OuterBox` and `.InnerBox`, then use proper `z-index` and a successor selector `~`:

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.limiter {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.OuterBox {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://www.dictionary.com/e/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/vscogirl1000x700.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

.OuterBox:hover,
.InnerBox:hover~.OuterBox { /* This line */
  transform: scale(1.5);
}


/* Overlay */

.OuterBox::after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.InnerBox {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: white solid 5px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1; /* And this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="limiter">
  <div class="InnerBox">
    <div>
      <h2>CLICK HERE</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="OuterBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. I was going crazy over this one :D